# Why is my quicksort so inefficient?

Tags: c++, quicksort

I've made a quicksort from a variety of sources online and made mine using the technique of having the pivot in the centre and not the first or last index like some others did.

However, the sort ends up breaking my program over 80 elements as it just freezes and I'm assuming it's because it's being inefficient with memory.

The data it's trying to sort is by no way already sorted and fully random.

```
void swapVecPos(int posOne, int posTwo)
{
    int temp = intVec[posOne];
    intVec[posOne] = intVec[posTwo];
    intVec[posTwo] = temp;
}

void sortShit(int leftValue, int rightValue)
{
    int left = leftValue;
    int right = rightValue;
    int pivot = intVec[(leftValue + rightValue) / 2];

    while(left <= right)
    {
        while(intVec[left] < pivot)
        {
            left++;
        }

        while(intVec[right] > pivot)
        {
            right--;
        }

        if(left <= right)
        {
            swapVecPos(left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    if(leftValue < right)
        sortShit(leftValue, right);

    if(left < rightValue)
        sortShit(left, intVec.size() - 1);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Start with a small collection, and step through the code in a debugger, line by line, to make sure the code does what you expect it to. Talking about expectations, for some specified input what is the expected *and* actual output? And how do you use the functions? Please provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can improve it by changing the `left <= right` conditions to simply `left < right` because there is no benefit to swapping an element with itself.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think that there's a bug there anyway.  If `right == left`, then he'll end up with `right < left`, which isn't what he wants.  For that matter, if `left == right - 1`, he'll have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two obvious errors in your code.  First, if at any
time the pivot is the smallest or the largest value (and that
will happen at some time if the values are random), you leave
the partition you're working on.  If the partition is the first
or the last, this may result in undefined behavior, but in any
case, it will not give the right results.

Second: when you're recursing, the second recursion uses
`intVect.size()`, so it calls the function on everything which
remains.  This is surely the cause of the symptom you're seeing.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "leave the partition you're working on".  You mean recursion happens on the same range?  Or that there's an out-of-bounds access?

Comment: @BenVoigt Out of bounds access if your partition is at the end.  Otherwise, you're comparing a value which isn't in the partition you're supposed to be looking at.

Comment: Ok, so you mean leave==exit, rather than "leave alone".  Perhaps s/leave/index outside/, then

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

> ```
> sortShit(left, intVec.size() - 1);
> ```

Some other branch of the recursion is responsible for sorting between `rightValue+1` and `intVec.size()-1`.  You only need to recurse using

```
sortShit(left, rightValue);
```

which restores the invariant that recursive calls are always on successively smaller sets, and therefore terminate.

Your call allows the size of the right-hand set to grow, and therefore doesn't guarantee termination.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, your answer made it run much faster already, and I haven't finished yet! ^^